# Reduce space between axis and geom

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot that looks like this:

[image]

How can I remove the space between the laft edge of the line and the y axis without cutting off my directlabels?

The code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
labs <- c("Special Ed., Charter School", 
    "Gen. Ed., Charter School",
    "Special Ed., Public School", 
    "Gen. Ed., Public School")

pot <- data.frame(Engagement = c(643, 793, 590, 724, 735, 928, 863, 662),
    Classroom = rep(rep(c("Special Ed.", "Gen. Ed."), each = 2), 2),
    Gender = factor(rep(c("Male", "Female"), 4), levels = c("Male", "Female")),
    School = rep(c("Charter", "Public"), each = 4), 
    ID = factor(rep(1:4, each = 2)),
    labs = factor(rep(labs, each=2), levels=labs)
    )

library(directlabels)

xout <- ggplot(pot, aes(y = Engagement, x = Gender, group = ID)) + 
    geom_line(aes(color=labs), size=2) + theme_classic() +
    scale_x_discrete(expand = c(.1, .3)) +
    scale_color_hue(l=40) +
    theme(text = element_text(size=22))   

direct.label(xout, list('last.qp', cex=1.35))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Workaround would be to add empty level to Gender.

```
pot$Gender<-factor(pot$Gender,levels=c("Male","Female",""))
```

Then in `scale_x_discrete()` use `drop=FALSE` to show this level. Now you can change also `expand=` values.

```
 + scale_x_discrete(expand = c(0.01, 0.01),drop=FALSE)
```

[image]

Other possibility is to use your `Gender` as numeric and then with `scale_x_continuous()` set `limits=` and then provide `breaks=` and `labels=` to get correct labeling again.

```
xout <- ggplot(pot, aes(y = Engagement, x = as.numeric(Gender), group = ID)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color=labs), size=2) + theme_classic() +
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0),"Gender",breaks=c(1,2),
               labels=c("Male","Female"),limits=c(0.95,4)) +
  scale_color_hue(l=40) +
  theme(text = element_text(size=22))
```